# Indent list item of bulleted list in table in Outlook WordEditor

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to compose an email with Outlook VBA with data from an Excel sheet.

I pasted a table from Excel into the mail and now want to format some cells as a bulleted list inside the table.

Now I need to format the text of the cell e.g. as a bulleted list.

This works with this code:

```
Dim currentCell As Variant
currentCell = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2)
currentCell.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

How would I format the text in the Cell(2,2) as a bulleted list with multiple indentations?

When I use `currentCell.ListFormat.ListIndent` the whole cell shifts to the left, not just the list.

This is the structure I am looking for
[image: Picture: This is the structure I am looking for]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this works when you're in Outlook, but in Word you would need to create a ListTemplate with the relevant bullet style layout, then apply it. Something like this:

```
Const bulletLTName As String = "mybullet"
With ActiveDocument
  ' Unless you are always creating new documents, you might
  ' need to verify that mybullet doesn't exist and delete then recreate,
  ' or modify. Not done here.
  With .ListTemplates.Add(OutlineNumbered:=False, Name:=BulletLTName)
    With .ListLevels(1)
      .NumberFormat = "-"
      ' If you need to modify the bullet font, you can do it
      ' like this...
      With .Font
        .Name = "<whatever font name you want to use>"
        .Size = 10 ' etc.
      End With
      ' You can modify other layout properties - best to
      ' look at Word's object model, but for example
      .NumberPosition = 0
      .TabPosition = 10
      .TextPosition = 10 ' and so on.
    End With
  End With
  With .Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range
    .Text = "text"
    .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate .Document.ListTemplates(bulletLTName)
  End With
End With
```

Although it does function, I would try to avoid defining currentCell as a Variant because it makes the code less obvious (e.g. it's not obvious that, as written, currentCell is a Word Range and not a Word Cell).

Comment: Thank you this helps! One additional question. When I do ```currentCell.ListFormat.ListIndent``` the whole cell of the table indents, not just the list in the cell. Which then breaks the table. How can I fix this?

Comment: I want to increase the Tab to the right (indent the ListLevel). Therefore I tried ```
With .ListLevels(1)
          .NumberFormat = "-"
          .TabPosition = 50
          .NumberPosition = 20
        End With
```
but both don't have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This VBA function creates a mail and adds a bullet list in the mail body.
Now you just need to replace the `text` variable with the data from the cells

```
Sub send()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim text As String

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    text = "This is a summary" & Chr(10) & _
    Chr(149) & " First point" & Chr(10) & _
    Chr(149) & " Second point" & Chr(10) & _
    Chr(149) & " Last point"

    With objMail
       .To = "name@domain.de"
       .Subject = "Subject"
       .Body = text
       .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to add a bullet list into one cell you can use the same method, e.g. the below code adds the list into the current active cell:

```
Sub Bullets()
    Text = "This is a summary" & Chr(10) & _
        Chr(149) & " First point" & Chr(10) & _
        Chr(149) & " Second point" & Chr(10) & _
        Chr(149) & " Last point"

    ActiveCell.Value = Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to keep the excel table in the email. I edited my question for clarification. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I want to keep the text that already is in the table cell and format it as a bulleted list. This solution would replace the data. I think it's done with ```ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate```, but I cant figure out how?

Comment: The point I am after here is to use `Chr(149)` as bullet. Of coarse you need to replace the `text` variable with the already exisiting data in the cell and combine it with `Chr(149)`.

Comment: I understood your point, but still it's not the result that I want as if the content is multiple lines long it's not properly indented like a bulleted list. I attached a picture of the structure I want to my question.